# Excel connecting to wrong instance of SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have SQL Server 2008 Express and SQL Server 2012 Developer Edition installed on my local machine.

The usual connection to Express looks something like this:

SERVERNAME\SQLEXPRESS

The connection to SQL Server 2012 should be this:

SERVERNAME\MSSQLSERVER,1433

The problem is that when I use the supposed connection to SQL Server 2012, Excel shows me tables that are in the Express instance.

I have ODBC connections that refer to each instance separately and successfully but for some reason this doesn't work. Could the problem be that both instances are using the same port?

Update: In case you're wondering why I was specifying the port, it's because I couldn't connect to any database with just SERVERNAME\MSSQLSERVER (but, again, using the port connected me to Express). As a test just now, I stopped all Express services and now I can connect to SQL Server 2012 using just the server name (i.e., SERVERNAME without a service name).

Still, I'm curious to know what was going on there.

Comment: Which Excel version? You might be better of at [superuser: cannot connect-to-sql-server-from-excel-2007](http://superuser.com/questions/314206/cannot-connect-to-sql-server-from-excel-2007)

Comment: Sorry -- Excel 2010. Actually, I read that first which is where I found the advice about adding the port. This is resolved for now but I'm curious to know if it was a common ports issue (between the two instances).

Comment: if you resolved it it would be nice if you add an answer so that others facing the same problem can find a solution here.

Comment: Well, I solved the issue of being able to use my SQL Server 2012 instance but my real question is what is happening in the scenario I described above? Is it a ports issue? If I don't see an answer to that, I'll answer my own question.